# Mips assembly simulator in C++

Tags: c++, assembly, mips, simulator

uni student here and just learning the ropes, i've been tasked to make a mips assembly simulator in C++, i've currently got it running to read from file which was a very easy way of implementing it but was wondering, would it be better to make it user input based in the console itself or is it better to just keep it reading from the imem.txt file? any help would be greatly appreciated, i've posted below the imem reading file code.

```
class INSMem {

public:

    bitset<32> Instruction;    // The current instruction

    INSMem() {

        IMem.resize(MemDepth); // Resize the IMem vector to the specified memory depth

        ifstream imem;
        string line;
        int i = 0;
        imem.open("imem.txt");  // Open the imem.txt file

        if (imem.is_open()) {

            while (getline(imem, line)) {

                IMem[i] = bitset<8>(line); // Read each line from the imem.txt file and store it as an 8-bit bitset in the IMem vector
                i++;

            }

        }
        else {

            cout << "Unable to open file." << endl; // Display an error message if unable to open the file

        }

        imem.close(); // Close the file after reading is done
```

Comment: OT: Keep your constructors small and simple. Don't do any processing (like reading a file) in it. It should only initialize the object and its members to a known state, nothing more.

Comment: Reading from a file if one is given, otherwise stdin, is normal for programs.  Some don't accept a filename and only read from stdin, which makes it simpler to write.  You can redirect input from a file if you want.  But it's more of a pain to connect stdin to a named file, e.g. `cat` into a named pipe or something on Unix/Linux.

Comment: I am on windows. Thought about using stdin, but since i've already written it to read from file but since reading from file is already there, would it be better for me efficiency wise to make it read from user input in console? currently the user has to open the imem file, input the binary code of the instruction and then relaunch, which seems a bit hectec, especially for a project where the enduser wants a fully fledged program .

Comment: Unsure what the actual question is? is it related to the title?

Comment: There's not enough context here to say what you should do.  However, as critique, you're showing an object that has a field `Instruction` that is never used as far as we can tell.  The object appears to have no value post creation, basically a procedure (masquerading as a constructor) that modifies what appears to be a global variable (`IMem`).

Comment: Taken together (object that has no purpose as an object, plus use of mutable global variable for output), this is not really OOP.  To be clear, it is ok to have procedures, we don't have to use classes everywhere.  It is also ok to have singletons (globals) but should have a reason for them, and probably not necessary in your larger design, so just pass some parameters.

Comment: @ErikEidt I believe that `Instruction` is just the dereferenced value at `$pc`, so for example if `$pc = 0x00000200` then `Instruction` is the four bytes at that address.